# Alignment of secondary info in a list

Tags: info-visualisation

I am working on a drop list component with 2 information by row.
in this exemple : the animal usual name and its scientifical name

What alignment seems better for the second information ? 
• Left like if it was a table
• Right like a secondary information
[image: Capture]
here is an Axure prototype : 
http://mrnot7.axshare.com/#g=1

Comment: I don't have a conclusive answer, so I'm adding this as a comment rather than an answer. I personally find the "table-like" version more scanable. You could even bring the scientific names more to the left, placing them directly behind the regular names, as long as they have a different color, they will be two seperate things.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, both the name and the description is valuable for the user. Seing both makes the user more confident that he has found the item he/she is looking for.

Then why not remove the white space and use the space available?

I.e. like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite a tricky question in my opinion, and instead of providing an exact answer, I'll highlight a few points based on your proposed design (and possible alternatives).

As you know, a lot of design depends on the content, and here you are dealing with text information that can actually vary significantly in length. Not only can normal animal names span a range of characters (e.g. giant armadillo vs. ant), even the scientific name can vary a lot in length as well. In addition, I don't think there's really any relationship between the length of the normal and scientific name. Basically that just means you are designing for two variable width columns (which you have to truncate at some predefined point to cater for most lengths).

So looking at the design on the left, it seems to cater for cases when the left hand column can have a number of very long values, because the right alignment puts the focus on the left column better. However, if the right column contains a higher amount of characters it might throw the balance of the design out a bit.

And looking at the design on the left, it works well for cases when the left and right hand column has balanced amount of content overall, otherwise it would leave one or both sides looking a bit empty due to the fixed width on the columns.

But I think the best answer comes from how the user is going to scan and view the information presented to them and adjusting the default column width and alignment based on the content that will show the most amount of information for each column respectively.

Answer (score 0):

While having a bunch of left-aligned texts, in general, is easier, as they start in the same place within a row, I would go for the right aligned one.

The reason is simple, and can be decomposed into several aspects:

**White spaces aspect of the problem.**

Having secondary info left-aligned, you need to assign some space for it, which reduces the whitespace between the primary and secondary and leaving some space at the right side of the secondary (visible especially in case of shorter secondary info texts).

**Long secondary info making it worse.**

Now, sometimes the secondary info may be quite long, actually. It is often a little bit descriptive, giving more details about the matter indicated by the primary text. As a result, you need to assign quite a lot space for this secondary info. Which, again is often not used, so it makes the problem of white spaces even more problematic.

**Finally, long primary info.**

One day a situation will appear when the primary information will be long. This way, having your secondary info left aligned may lead to a situation, when a quite long primary info will be followed (just a few pixels later) with a short secondary info, and then a long white space.

So, I would suggest to align primary left, and secondary right. Of course approaches may vary, I just believe in this being superior.